# Closedness of the closed half-space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a hyperplane $H(p, \alpha) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\mid p \cdot x = \alpha\}$ , then how do we prove that one of the corresponding closed half-spaces, $H^*(p, \alpha) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid p \cdot x \leq α\}$ is indeed closed?

For every $x$ that is an element of  the complement of  $H^*(p, \alpha)$, can we find an associated $r > 0$ such that a ball centered at $x$ with the radius $r$ is a subset of the complement of $H^*(p, \alpha)$ and therefore proving that the complement of $H^*(p, \alpha)$ is open and $H^*(p, \alpha)$ is indeed closed. I am having trouble finding this $r > 0$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ and $a$ be given, and suppose that $p\cdot x > a$ for some $x$. The goal is to show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $p \cdot (x+y) > a$ for all $y$ satisfying $|y| < \delta$. If $\epsilon = p\cdot x -a$, then everything works if $|p\cdot y| < \epsilon/2$, which is definitely accomplished if $|p||y| < \epsilon/2$. So, $\delta=\epsilon/2(|p|+1)$ works.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify a bit more, sorry I'm new to topology, why do you have p⋅(x+y)>a ? Why not  p⋅y > a for all y satisfying |y - x|<δ.  I thought we want to find δ > 0 so we can draw a ball around x  and for all y within this ball, p⋅y > a so this ball is entirely contained in the complement of H*(p, α). @T.A.E.

Comment: Starting as you did, we show that the one set is closed iff its complement is open. So fix $p$ and $a$. The complement of $\{ x : p\cdot x \le a \}$ is $\{ x : p\cdot x > a\}$. So you start with $x$ such that $p\cdot x > a$. let $\epsilon = p\cdot x - a$; so long as $|p\cdot y| < \epsilon/2$, then $p\cdot(x+y) = p\cdot x-p\cdot y > p\cdot x - \epsilon/2 > a$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Using the result, if the function $f$ is continuous and set $D$ is closed, the for any real $\alpha$, the level set $\{x \in D | f(x) \leq \alpha\}$ is closed.